# Migrate to Cloud Tools for Eclipse and/or the GWT Eclipse Plugin as soon as possible to avoid disruption For this MAVEN is Mandatory ?

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, gwt

I have GWT 2.6.1 with google app engine server application which run successfully. now i have updated my project using this [Cloud Tools for Eclipse](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/) and [GWT Eclipse Plugin](http://gwt-plugins.github.io/documentation/) because `" The Google Plugin for Eclipse is deprecated and will be removed in January 2018. Migrate to Cloud Tools for Eclipse and/or the GWT Eclipse Plugin as soon as possible to avoid disruption "`. So My existing project i am not using Maven Now i want to deploy my application on google app engine server So MAVEN Integration is Mandatory ? My existing GWT + Google app engine application can i able to deploy without MAVEN ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer: no, you're not required to change your projects to use Maven to use the new Cloud Tools for Eclipse (CT4E).  But CT4E does make use of facilities from M2Eclipse, the Maven tooling for Eclipse, and so we require that it be installed.